# Upgrade ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0 startup not creating controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a solution that is being upgraded from RC1 to Core 1.0. The solution contains several projects (API,business,tests and specflow tests), these have all been upgraded successfully (i.e. they compile!) and the site runs.

However the specflow project spins up a test server and runs test against it (All in memory). After upgrading none of the specflow tests work. The specflow project has its own startup class that creates mock services for things like email and message queues.

When creating the server in the test project we use (worked OK in RC1)

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<StartupSpecTest>
var currentClient = TestServer(host).CreateClient();
```

However this now always returns "not found" 
When we change the startup to use the startup in the API Project

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>
```

Then we get a valid response.

I then tried copying the setup class from the API project to the spec test project, but I get the same response (Not found). Does anybody know if something has changed when trying to call a test server with a setup class from a different assembly?